# Check if an Add-in is installed and running VBA

Tags: excel, add-in, solver, vba

I am trying to check if an add-in is installed and running. I am using this piece of code:

```
On Error Resume Next:

Set SolverNome1 = AddIns("Solver Add-In") 'Solver may have two different names
Set SolverNome2 = AddIns("Solver")
MsgBox IsEmpty(SolverNome1)
MsgBox IsEmpty(SolverNome2)

If IsEmpty(SolverNome1) And IsEmpty(SolverNome2) Then
    MsgBox "Install Solver add-in before trying to install this add-in.", vbExclamation
    Application.myAddInName.Installed = False 'uninstall my add-in
End If
```

The problem is that even with the Solver Uninstalled I still get IsEmpty(SolverNome1) = false so my condition clause doesn't work as desired. I guess there I am misunderstanding the concept of installed or not. What piece of code should I be using to check if solver is running?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my on question:
It is necessary to access the .installed property like this:

myBoolean1 = SolverNome1.Installed 'will return false because the add-in is set and not installed
myBoolean2 = SolverNome1.Installed 'won't return because add-in is not set